# WriteFile with DLLs

Tags: c++, dll

Im writing a DLL and I want to write some data to a file (150k+)

The problem is - WriteFile is not writing everything it should write

It looks like the thread gets terminated before WriteFile finish its work.

any ideas ? thanks

Comment: Some small code snippet will be more informative...

Comment: Well, if the thread gets terminated, find where that happens and stop terminating it.

Answer (score 3):

If you exit your process before the thread completes, all other threads will be terminated (from [ExitProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682658(VS.85).aspx)):

> Exiting a process causes the
>   following:
>
> 1. **All of the threads in the process, except the calling thread,
>      terminate their execution without
>      receiving a DLL_THREAD_DETACH
>      notification.**
> 2. The states of all of the threads terminated in step 1 become signaled.
> 3. The entry-point functions of all loaded dynamic-link libraries (DLLs)
>      are called with DLL_PROCESS_DETACH.
> 4. After all attached DLLs have executed any process termination code,
>      the ExitProcess function terminates
>      the current process, including the
>      calling thread.
> 5. The state of the calling thread becomes signaled.
> 6. All of the object handles opened by the process are closed.
> 7. The termination status of the process changes from STILL_ACTIVE to
>      the exit value of the process.
> 8. The state of the process object becomes signaled, satisfying any
>      threads that had been waiting for the
>      process to terminate.

You will need to explicitly wait for the thread executing WriteFile to complete, usually via `WaitForSingleObject(thread handle, ...)`.

Comment: Also note that if the process is terminated (rather than exited), it's even worse -- `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` is not called in that case.